# Recursion function and helper function to add two char type numbers in C

Tags: c, string, recursion, char

I keep getting stuck as to how to write a helper function and recursion function for adding two numbers.

The problem specifies to use char *add2(char *n1, char *n2) to call a helper function and use it in the main function. However I keep getting an error because you cannot add two chars together. How do I solve this?

Comment: If you have `char c1 = 1; char c2 = 2;` you can write `char c3 = c1 + c2;` and `c3` will contain `3`.  Note that if you used `char c1 = '1'; char c2 = '2'; char c3 = c1 + c2;` then `c3` would contain `'c'` and not `'3'` if you use a codeset based on ASCII (ISO 8859-x, Unicode).  You can't add pointers; you can add dereferenced pointers (`int i = *n1 + *n2;` etc).

Answer (score 1):

C does not have a string concatentation operator.  Look up how to use strdup() and strcat(), that should help you.

To understand the problem, think of smult as "string multiplication", where "s" x 1 = "s", "s" x 2 = "ss", "s" x 3 = "sss" etc.